# Composing URL in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, url, jstl, el

Lets say my current URL is:
 `/app.jsp?filter=10&sort=name`.

I have a pagination component in JSP which should contain links like:
 
`/app.jsp?filter=10&sort=name&page=xxx`.

How do I create valid URLs in JSP by adding new parameters to current URL? I dont want use Java code in JSP, nor end up with URLs like: 
`/app.jsp?filter=10&sort=name&?&page=xxx`, or `/app.jsp?&page=xxx`, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I found answer. First problem is that I have to preserve all current parameters in URL and  change only `page` parameter. To do this I have to iterate over all current parameters and add those I don't want to change to URL. Then I added parameters I want to either change or add. So I ended up with solution like this:

```
<c:url var="nextUrl" value="">
    <c:forEach items="${param}" var="entry">
        <c:if test="${entry.key != 'page'}">
            <c:param name="${entry.key}" value="${entry.value}" />
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:param name="page" value="${some calculation}" />
</c:url>
```

This will create nice and clean URL independent of `page` parameter in request. Bonus to this approach is that URL can be just anything.

Answer (score 9):

```
<c:url var="myURL" value="/app.jsp">
   <c:param name="filter" value="10"/>
   <c:param name="sort" value="name"/>
</c:url>
```

To show the url you can do something like this

```
<a href="${myURL}">Your URL Text</a>
```

Comment: unfortunately my pagination component (because of reuse) don't know which parameter are valid for URL and also cannot set them by it's self. It can only add parameter page

Comment: then you can check it <c:if test="${param.filter is empty}">your code is here</c:if>

Comment: i.e adding parameter page `<c:param name="page" value="${page}"/>` where `page` is a request attr and will be parameter in the url, if you need parameter instead of attr then use `param` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

To construct a new URL based on the current URL, you first need to **get the current URL from the `request` object**. To access the `request` object in a JSP use `pageContext` [**implicit object**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij) defined by the JSP expression language:

```
${pageContext.request.requestURL}
```

---

Here is the simple example of constructing URL in a JSP page:

*test.jsp*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Testing URL construction</h1>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${pageContext.request.queryString != null}">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.requestURL}?${pageContext.request.queryString}&page=xxx">Go to page xxx</a>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <a href="${pageContext.request.requestURL}?page=xxx">Go to page xxx</a>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</body>
</html>
```

This solution allows you to construct URLs **depending on whether the current URL already contains some query string or not**. So you respectively append either

`?${pageContext.request.queryString}&page=xxx`

or just

`?page=xxx`

to the current URL.

[JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) and the [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) were used to implement checking for a query string. And we used [`getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()) method to obtain the current URL.