# session.getAttribute() in JSP is giving null value

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

Here is my HTML code in JSP

```
<select name="urlsel" id="selurl">
<option value="eng" name="eng"/>
<option value="mat" name="mat"/>
<option value="sci" name="sci"/>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit option" onsubmit="return validate()"/>
<%  String opt=session.getAttribute("urlsel");
    System.out.println("\n selected optiion is:+opt)
%>
```

The above JSP code is giving **null** value for **opt**. I tried with `request.getParameter("urlsel");` in JSP still getting **null**.

I want the selected option value answer with `session.getAttribute("urlsel");`

How can I get it? I want this value in my servlet and in servlet using `session.getAttribute("urlsel");`
but getting null.

Please help me.

Comment: Are you ever setting the session attribute?  Since you tried both a session attribute and request parameter, which have nothing to do with each other, I'm guessing that you are trying to do something client-side?  JSP doesn't make sense for that.

Comment: Not related to your question.. You are using Scriplets which is no more used these days. Instead replace them with [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get attributes from a *session* or a *request*, before doing that you must set/add it somewhere in your code (i.e. **first** set attributes, **then** you can get them).

So the short answer: **in your case**, instead of using `getAttribute(String name)` on *session* or *request* object, use **`request.getParameter(String name)`**.

---

What you're trying to accomplish here is retrieving **parameters** passed using HTML form. In order to do that use [`getParameter(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) method, like:

`String selectValue = request.getParameter("urlsel")`

**Traditionally values passed using HTTP form are retrieved in a servlet** and then you can do whatever you need to do with them.

As I can see in your example, you are doing this *PHP* way. Although not the most common way in Java Web Application development, but you can retrieve parameters passed using HTML form in JSP from the *param* [implicit object](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij) using [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) (you should [avoid scriptlets in your JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/814702)).

---

### Simple example

This is a simple example of a JSP page to showcase retrieving a parameter submitted using HTML *form* element in the same page (as in your example):

*test.jsp*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <p>Choose some course</p>
        <select name="course">
            <option value="English" name="eng">English</option>
            <option value="Math" name="mat">Math</option>
            <option value="Computer Science" name="sci">Computer Science</option>
        </select>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Pass data" /></p>
    </form>
    <hr />
    <h2>Testing passed parameters</h2>
    <p>Passed "course" parameter = <span style="color: #FF0000">${param.course}</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the usage of *EL*: `${param.course}`, where "*param*" is the name of one of the [implicit objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij), and "*course*" is the name of the *select* element, whose value was passed by submitting the HTML form.

Also check out the following answer for the additional information: [Passing variables from JSP to servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15797418/814702).

---

P.S.

You may find it useful to read some tutorials covering servlets and JSP. Here is a popular tutorial with nice explanations and easy to understand examples:

[Beginning & Intermediate Servlet & JSP Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)

Comment: I need the selected value not only for one time in servlet.My jsp is getting refreshed for every 10 seconds.In that case it is unable to get the already selected option.So I am trying with sessions.But unable to get the values using session.getAttribute()

Comment: @user2515189 As I already wrote, you **first** need to put the value in *session*, **only then** you can get it from there. Like `String selectValue = request.getParameter("urlsel"); request.getSession().setAttribute("urlsel", selectValue)`, something like that. Plus you never wrote anything about refreshing your page and preserving the selected value. **Please try to be precise about the details when writing your question**.

Comment: @user2515189 I have posted [an answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17302734/814702), where you described the refresh issue.