# Maintain persistent state of <select> statement using servlet

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, servlets

I am making a simple web app using servlet and JSP, which have multiple drop down lists in a form tags. Now when I change the value in the drop down and the form is submitted, it changes its value to the default, Now I want the drop down list to maintain its state even after being submitted or keep the last selected value selected after submission.

Below is my jsp code:

```
<p style="font-weight: bold">select options</p>
       <select id="opt" name="selOpt">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option>sel1</option>
          <option>sel2</option>
        </select>
```

and this is how my servlet handle request method is:

```
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
  String selection= req.getParameter("selOpt");
if(selection.isEmpty()){

    /** some logic implemented */
    }else {
    /** logic implemented */
```

Can anyone please help how can I achieve a persistent state of selection in using servlet and jsp? any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you'll find it useful: [Preserving the selected value in an HTML select element after refreshing a JSP page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17302734/814702)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `selected="true"` attribute on the option element to make it selected by default.

```
<select id="opt" name="selOpt">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option>sel1</option>
  <option selected="true">sel2</option>
</select>
```

You can either use jsp to check if selected option is selected and dynamically generate the `selected="true"` attribute, or use javascript / jquery to select it on the client side.